# BASH: compare the size to a percent part of another file's size

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following situation:

```
A=$(df / | awk 'END{print $4}')
B=$(du -s /tmp | awk '{print $1}')
```

The condition is to alert when $B is less then 10% of $A size.

the way below i used doesn't seem to recognize '-lt' :

```
A=$(df / | awk 'END{print $4}')
B=$(du -s /tmp | awk '{print $1}')

if $(($A / $B)) -lt '10'
        then  echo "Bad case"
fi

: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `-lt'
: line 8: `if (($A / $B)) -lt '10''
```

Any ideas how can it be achieved?

Comment: If you use bash arithmetic expressions you can just `if ((A/B<10)); then...`. Beware, this is integer arithmetic (rounding, truncation...)

Comment: Also, note that `B / A < 0.10` (i.e your "$B is less than 10% of $A") implies that `A / B > 10`, not `A / B < 10` as you've currently coded... Basic arithmetic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget `[]` in if statement:

```
if [ $(($A / $B)) -lt '10' ]
    then  echo "BLYAD"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A=$(df / | awk 'END{print $4}')
B=$(du -s /tmp | awk '{print $1}')
echo $A $B | awk '{C = 10*B; if (C < A) print "Bad case"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (( A < 10 * B ))
then
  echo "Bad case"
fi
```

In bash, you can't do fractional arithmetic. Hence you should either rewrite the expression so that it doesn't need fractions or use zsh, which has floating point arithmetic.